# In the netbox plugin development tutorial, where is manage.py being run from?

Tags: django, netbox

I am following the tutorial on plugin development at https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plugins/development/

I have gone as far as creating the models and want to make migrations...

However, the `manage.py` is not found in the root of my plugin folder.

Where is it expected that `manage.py` is?

Comment: The pluggings are supposed to be [reusable Django apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/reusable-apps/), which doesn't have `manage.py`.

Answer (score 1):

The `manage.py`is part of the Django application (= website). It is located in the Django root folder, see e.g. [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/).

So, a plugin never has got its own `manage.py`, but it may have got a set of `migration` files that are used by the Django app when `python manage.py migrate` is invoked and the plugin has been installed and defined as being a part of the Django app (within `settings.py`).

Comment: I agree. But the question is what `manage.py` file am I supposed to use to create the migrations in the plugin? Am I to use the `django-admin` binary with `django-admin makemigrations my_plugin_plugin`? Trying that I set `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting STATIC_URL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: I would suggest to create a Django app using the `django-admin startproject mysite` command. This will be an empty app initially. Then install your plugin, include it in the `settings.py` of the created app and then run `makemigrations`. This will create the migration files that you can then use as part of your plugin package.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've followed the installation instructions and installed Netbox in `/opt/netbox`, the `manage.py` file you need to use is located in `/opt/netbox/netbox/` folder.

Don't forget to activate the virtual environment in `/opt/netbox/venv` and to set `DEVELOP` to True in `/opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/configuration.py`